# work around to replace item in foreach loop

Tags: c#, key-value

In my example code below i would like to replace the item in the dictionary with a new item or  assign new values to that item. **How can i do this?**

This is my code:

```
dynamic data = jss.Deserialize<dynamic>(jsonText);

foreach (KeyValuePair<string,object> item in data["typeData"])
{
    if(item.Key == "somevalue")
        {
            item = new KeyValuePair<string,object>();
        }                               
}
```

I'm getting:

> Cannot assign to 'item' because it is a 'foreach iteration variable'

There must be a work-around.

Comment: What are you **really** trying to do? Why would you have an empty `KeyValuePair`? How could more than one item have the key `"somevalue"` (i.e. why do you need to loop)?

Comment: Very good point Karl (why do you need to loop). that's key.

Comment: Well, it's your code and your coding problem, so you tell me! :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Depends on what you want. Do you just need to override the value? I assume so because replacing the key and value would be a very different operation (remove one item and insert another)

just iterate over the keys instead of the collection (Assuming it's a dictionary):

```
dynamic data = jss.Deserialize<dynamic>(jsonText)["typeData"];

foreach (string key in data.Keys)
{
    if(key == "somevalue")
        {
            data[key] = ...;
        }                               
}
```

if there's no keys property you can substitute that part with (assuming that at least there's an indexer)

```
foreach (string key in data.Select(pair=>pair.Key)){
  ...
}
```

Comment: Or, if he just needs to replace the value with the key "somevalue": `data["somevalue"] = ...;`

Comment: @phoog yeah but since he's looping I guess "someValue" is an example and that several values are possible

Comment: Yes, I thought of that too.  But then I thought that those several values would have to come from somewhere, and I can't think of anywhere they could come from that would make looping like this the best solution.

Answer (score 3):

`foreach` are considered to be read only contexts.

Don't use `foreach` as the message says, convert the loop to a regular `for` loop.

From MSDN:

```
This error occurs when an assignment to variable occurs in a read-
only context. Read-only contexts include foreach iteration variables,
using variables, and fixed variables. To resolve this error, avoid
assignments to a statement variable in using blocks, foreach
statements, and fixed statements.
```

In your case the object `item` is not a reference its simply a copy hence any change you make to it will not result in a change in the original object.

Comment: sounds simple but i the dynamic datatype has not .count or .length for that loop. Please give an example.

Comment: @capdragon - loop through the original list using foreach and store a reference to what needs to be changed in the original list (into a new list) then use a foreach for the new list to update the original list.  But as `Karl Knechtel` mentioned in your comments, how could more then one item have the same key?

Comment: @capdragon - "data" is dynamic. It appears to be a Bag of some sort, within which an item keyed "typeData" is a Dictionary. There would need to be some explicit cast of that item to a Dictionary type so the foreach knows what it's working with, but it's only minimally relevant to the question of how to change elements of that Dictionary.

Comment: "somevalue" is actually a funtion that calls gets a value.. not important.

Answer (score 1):

The problem with your code is that you are attempting to change the value of a variable that is used as a placeholder. The variable "item" simply has the same reference that exists in the dictionary; changing the object that "item" references won't actually change anything in the Dictionary itself, and on top of that it can screw up the logic of looping through the Dictionary.

In addition to not being able to reassign the placeholder, you are not allowed to add or remove items from the Dictionary within a foreach loop that uses said Dictionary, because that will also mess up the logic of iterating through the Dictionary's items (the item that is the "current" item of the enumerator behind the scenes now no longer exists, so the enumerator may lose its place in the collection and not be able to continue.

The workaround is to enumerate a different collection when you change the original collection. Basically, a task like this requires two passes; first collect the items you want to change, then enumerate through THAT collection and make the change to the original collection:

```
...

var itemsToChange = new List<KeyValuePair<string, object>>();

foreach (var item in data["typeData"])
{
    if(item.Key == "somevalue")
       itemsToChange.Add(item);                                       
}

foreach(var item in itemsToChange)
{
    //even here you can't just "swap out" KVPs;
    //you must remove the old and add the new
    data["typeData"].Remove(item);
    data["typeData"].Add(someNewString, someNewObject);
}
```

Comment: Why was this negated?  This is just one method that would work +1.

Comment: I sure didn't DV but possibly because you don't need two passes but can do it in one (OP is asking for a substitution so add/remove shouldn't be necessary)

Comment: This is the straightforward approach

Answer (score 1):

You have to either use a for loop or store the variables you want changed and change them outside of the foreach loop.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps there's something missing from your question, but it seems that the workaround is to avoid looping entirely:

```
dynamic data = jss.Deserialize<dynamic>(jsonText); 
var item = new KeyValuePair<string, object>("somevalue", data["somevalue"]);
```

or perhaps:

```
dynamic data = jss.Deserialize<dynamic>(jsonText);
DoSomethingWith(data["somevalue"]);
```

what's the reason for your loop?